# jquery ui tabs problems with internet explorer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

i'm using

jquery - 1.4.4

jquery ui - 1.8.17

and on any version of Internet Explorer i'm having problems with tabs..

[image]

as u see, some of the tab contents is shown outside the tab divs

and this is my code:

```
<div id="tab_documents" class="ui-set-tabs" style="min-height: 150px">
    <ul class="tabNavigation">
        <li><a href="#tab_model"><?php $this->lang->cout("messages_sms_other")?></a></li>
        <li id='tab_dest_title' <?php  echo isset($enable_tabs) ? '' : 'class="ui-state-disabled"' ?>><a href="#tab_dest"><?php $this->lang->cout("attrs_destination")?></a></li>
        <li id='tab_params_title' <?php  echo isset($enable_tabs) ? '' : 'class="ui-state-disabled"' ?>><a href="#tab_params"><?php $this->lang->cout('documentemissions_params')?></a></li>
        <li id='tab_attach_title'  <?php  echo isset($enable_tabs) ? '' : 'class="ui-state-disabled"' ?>><a href="#tab_attach"><?php $this->lang->cout('attrs_attachments') ?></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id='tab_model'> content </div>
<div id='tab_dest'> content </div>
<div id='tab_params'> content </div>
<div id='tab_attach'> content </div>
```

so when i click on 3rd or 4rd tabs, internet explorer gives me this:

SCRIPT5022: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier. 
jquery-ui.min.1.8.17.js, line 181 character 6303

any help? thanks in advance

Comment: div with id="tab_documents" is not closed...

Comment: i forgot to copy that part... my bad

Answer (score 1):

First of all div with `id="tab_documents"` is not closed and perhaps there is version mismatch here. The version of `jQuery UI` you are using and the `jQuery` are not compatible. Perhaps 1.8.17 of `jQuery UI` came after 1.4.4 of `jquery`.

Try using latest version of both the libraries.
Get 1.8 + of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and 1.9.2 of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: i'll try it today, but i think that isn't the problem.. because i'm using this versions in all application... Anyway i'm gonna try that, and post.

Comment: First of all try closing the div tag as IE is not very lenient.